# How to delete two "tr" rows with js?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, c#-4.0

When I delete product into basket, products deleted successfully but company name does not delete. I'm using javascript. i cant solve the problem, help me pls...

[image]

```js
function getCurrentRow(t) {
  var v = parseInt($.trim(t.attr("data-row-id")));
  if (isNaN(v)) {
    console.log("data-row-id:null");
    return null;
  }
  var currentRow = getRow(v);
  if (currentRow == null) {
    console.log("currentRow:null");
    return null;
  }
  return currentRow;
}

// Delete
basketContainer.on('click', 'button[data-button-name="delete"]', function() {
  var o = $(this);

  var t = o.closest("tr");

  var currentRow = getCurrentRow(t);
  if (currentRow == null) {
    return;
  }
  postData(t, currentRow.index, {
    "basketid": currentRow.id,
    "pdoductid": currentRow.ProductID,
    "count": 0,
    "cmdtype": cmdTypes.Delete
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr data-row-id="item.id">
      <td colspan="4" style="color: #d53434">Shop: <strong>Shop name</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" data-row-id="item2.id">
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve] add your buttons and CSS and relevant HTML

Comment: Where is getRow and why do you have 2 functions to do what you already did with `var t = o.closest("tr");`

Comment: <tr data-row-id="item.id"> this is calling Shop Name and the other products. when i delete product, shop name doesnt deleted. can u help me pls

Comment: how can i solve this problem? when i delete product in tbody, it must be deleted thead row?

Answer (score 0):

You mean remove the table when no more products from that shop?

```js
$("#basketContainer").on('click', 'button[data-button-name="delete"]', function() {
  const $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  const $tb = $(this).closest("tbody");
  $tr.remove()
  if ($tb.find("tr").length === 0) $tb.closest("table").remove()

});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basketContainer">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr data-row-id="item.id">
        <td colspan="4" style="color: #d53434">Shop: <strong>Shop name 1</strong></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr role="row" data-row-id="item2.id">
        <td><button type="button" data-button-name="delete">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row" data-row-id="item2.id">
        <td><button type="button" data-button-name="delete">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr data-row-id="item.id">
        <td colspan="4" style="color: #d53434">Shop: <strong>Shop name 2</strong></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr role="row" data-row-id="item2.id">
        <td><button type="button" data-button-name="delete">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row" data-row-id="item2.id">
        <td><button type="button" data-button-name="delete">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: why u wirte table for 2?

Comment: @Shqiptar as an example

Comment: if ($tb.find("tr").length === 0) $tb.closest("table").remove() its doesnt work can u help me more plz?

Comment: all data deleting

Comment: What does `it doesn't work` mean. It works here so perhaps you have other errors? Anything in the console?

Comment: when i delete tbody, it must deleting thead data

Comment: I do not delete the tbody, I delete the nearest table

Comment: but when i delete tbody it must be deleted thead. i want to that. but i cant solve this problem.

Comment: I do not delete the tbody. You do. So our code is not the same - so show your code